# Is there any way to update only text of date picker content control, not the formatting detail?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-contentcontrol

I am working on one **word add-in** application in which I have several **date picker content controls**, setting the **text value** in to this content control **also changes the format of it** as per **system date format**.

I am setting up the **DateDisplayFormat** and **DateDisplayLocale** explicitly still it is showing date value as per system date format.

```
ContentControl.Range.Text = "21-12-16";
ContentControl.DateDisplayFormat ="yy-M-d";
ContentControl.DateDisplayLocale = 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLanguageID.wdSimplifiedChinese;
```

**My system date format : MM/dd/yyyy**

```
-Actual result : 16-12-21 (MM/dd/yyyy)
-Expected result : 21-12-16 (yy-M-d)
```

Comment: Are you sure `DateDisplayFormat` is `"yy-M-d"`? Shouldn't it be `"yy-MM-dd"`?

Comment: Yeah @Sach it is "yy-M-d" only. It is short date string format. [see this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSS28S_8.1.0/XFDL/i_xfdl_r_formats_zh_Hans_CN.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the ambiguity of `Range.Text = 16-12-21`.

This can be interpreted either way, as the year 2016 or as the year 2021. Word *does* rely on the Windows System settings for things like interpreting what a date should be, rather than anything local. I thought, perhaps switching the order of the format and data entry might have an influence, but it does not.

Simply provide a four-digit year, which is standard good-practice every since people realized the potential "millenium" problems back in the 1990's, and there's no issue. There's also no issue when someone uses the DatePicker in the UI. So...

```
ContentControl.Range.Text = "2021-12-16";
ContentControl.DateDisplayFormat ="yy-M-d";
ContentControl.DateDisplayLocale = 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLanguageID.wdSimplifiedChinese;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Cindy for your valuable comment and pointer.

The approach you suggested **provide four-digit year** is working fine, I verified it. 

Actually the thing is **we have implemented locale in our application** and user have choice to select locale and format, so, we don't have control on format.

It would be great if you can share some pointers around it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with locale, @RajnishJha. The code in the question indicates the date is being passed in by the code. That means the code can format it. You need to provide ***precise** information in questions so as not to waste people's time.

Comment: apologies @CindyMeister, if above comments was not clear to you. I accepted your approach as answer as I was able to proceed with that. 

Thanks once again.

Comment: @You're welcome :-) I'm glad things are working, now!